# Send discord webhook without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, discord

I'm trying to send a discord webhook message without jQuery.
I tried the following:

```
var sendWebhook = new XMLHttpRequest()

            sendWebhook.open("POST", $("webhook")[0].value)
            sendWebhook.onload = function() {
                if(sendWebhook.status === 200) {
                    Leaderboard.sendMessage("Webhook sent!")
                } else {
                    Leaderboard.sendMessage("Failed sending webhook...")
                }
            }
            sendWebhook.send({
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    content: "hi",
                    username: "hello",
                    avatar_url: ""
                })
            })
```

and so much other ways but it always fail! What's the problem?
Thanks!!

Comment: Any error messages? Why without jQuery, since you *are* using it? have you tried some basic debugging, as in inserting `console.log(...)` statements?

Comment: Oh, yea, sorry, so,
The error is an error 400, I read about it but so I don't know the problem, and yes I tried debugging a lot, but still the same... and... I'm not using JQuery.. $ is a selector I made

Comment: Ok, so what is `$("webhook")[0].value`? Does it correctly contain the URL? What does the API expect? Because you're passing an Object to `send()` which in turn contains a JSON String. Seems kind of inconsistent.

Comment: $("webhook")[0].value = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/***************/*****************webhook******************"

Comment: and I already tried by sending in not like an object but it wasnt still working

Comment: That `.value` looks wrong, because it will be appended to your current location. You need a full URL, starting with `https://`, or the browser will send the request to `http://yoursite.com/whatever/discordapp.com/api/webhooks`, which is probably not what you want

Comment: it starts with https://, stackoverflow just deleted it when I posted my comment...

Comment: So did you have jQuery code that worked? If so, could you add that to your question?

Answer (score 5):

A short, not object oriented version:

```
    function discord_message(webHookURL, message) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", webHookURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            'content': message,
            'username':'AI',
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your .send try not building a object with data, just pass the JSON.stringify function:

```
sendWebhook.send(JSON.stringify({
                    content: "hi",
                    username: "hello",
                    avatar_url: ""
                })
            )
```

If you look at your devtools in whichever browser you're testing in, you can see the payload being sent on the Network tab, and your request payload as you have it is a JavaScript object, which XmlHttpRequest cannot decipher.